# How do I add a new parameter to the current index in PrestaShop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How do I add a new parameter to the current index for the admin page (admin custom module) in PrestaShop?

I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
$this->setcurrentindex=$this->setcurrentindex.'&view=querydrlog';
```

What I need is:

```
http://localhost/raffleV1.3/oknr9hexztcseff5/index.php?controller=query&view=querydrlog&token=d81fcd49d179ae13444df0e8b2cccec6
```

When I click the `asc` or the pagination part the USL is:

```
http://localhost/raffleV1.3/oknr9hexztcseff5/index.php?controller=query&kits_query_drOrderby=id_query_dr&kits_query_drOrderway=desc&token=d81fcd49d179ae13444df0e8b2cccec6
```

To the above URL, I want to add `'&view=querydrlog';`, so that my pagination and `asc` will work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in your module admin controller by overriding the `init()` function of `AdminController`.

```
class YourAdminModuleController extends ModuleAdminController {
    protected $extra_params = '&view=querydrlog';

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        self::$currentIndex .= $this->extra_params;
        $this->context->smarty->assign('current', self::$currentIndex);
    }
}
```

This will add your parameter to sorting link hrefs or pagination form action link.

Answer (score 1):

Like @TheDrot but simpler:

```
class YourAdminModuleController extends ModuleAdminController {
    protected $extra_params = '&view=querydrlog';

    public function initProcess() {
        self::$currentIndex .= $this->extra_params;
        parent::initProcess();
    }
}
```